# Get call receive event in android

Tags: android, phone-call

Can I get incoming call pick up and end call event in android through coding? I want to that when I received incoming call then should be show toast message. Like incoming call I want to that when we end call then should be show toast message in my app.please suggest me.

Answer (score 4):

If you want it to only when your application's one activity then use following code :

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                // Incoming call: Pause music
                Log.i("Phone", "Ringing");

            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {


                Log.i("Phone", "Idle");
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                // A call is dialing, active or on hold
                Log.i("Phone", "offhook");

            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };
```

Or if you want to show toast eve outside of your application then try to make `service`.

There are some nice tutorials on service available.

First read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) on developer.

And also look into this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a BroadcastReceiver.  Try out this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html).